# show user via their profile slug

Tags: laravel

In my project I work with slugs to display posts, etc...

I do it this way and it works fine:

```
class Post extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'slug';
    }
}
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/{post}', [PublicPostController::class, 'show'])->name('public.post.show');
```

The problem comes now when I want to show a user through the slug, but the slug is not in the users table, but in the profile table.

```
Schema::create('profiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->string('slug')->unique();
            $table->text('biography')->nullable();
            $table->string('url')->nullable();
            $table->string('img_thumb')->nullable();
            $table->string('img_medium')->nullable();
            $table->string('img_large')->nullable();
            $table->enum('privacity', [Profile::PUBLICO, Profile::PRIVADO])->default(Profile::PUBLICO);
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

This is where I'm lost and I don't know how to approach it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define an [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) for this in your `User` model:

```php
protected $appends = ['slug'];

protected $with = ['profile'];

public function getSlugAttribute($value): string
{
    return $this->profile->slug;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a relationship between the user and profile page (Profile Belongs To User), then you retrive the user via the slug.

or if you want a simple way without relationship which i dont recommend:

//Get the profile from the request Slug.

```
$retriveProfile = Profile::where('slug',$request->slug)->firstOrFail();
```

//Get the user from the Profile we got of the slug.

```
$user = User::findOrFail($retriveProfile->user_id);
```

Comment: This won't work with route model binding as the model needs to be resolved before getting to the controller.